# Scroll bar wont go away on MUI masonry infinite scroll

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, scrollbar, infinite-scroll

I have a MUI Masonry element that takes in images for an infinite scroll. For some reason the css wont get rid of the scrollbar and I've tried everything I can think of.

The webkit display: 'none' used to work and then I added the array functionality and the scrollbar reappeared.

```
import { useRef, useCallback, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useInfiniteQuery } from 'react-query';
import { getImagesPage } from '../../../services/media.service';
import Masonry from '@mui/lab/Masonry';
import { styled } from '@mui/material/styles';
import { Box, Typography, Paper } from '@mui/material';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import { faCamera } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import { useMediaQuery } from '@mui/material';
import { useTheme } from '@mui/material';
import FileUpload from '../../../utils/Buttons/FileUpload';
import Skeleton from '@mui/material/Skeleton';


const ImageScroll = ({ listing, type, navigation }) => {
  const { Id } = useParams();
  const theme = useTheme();
  const small = useMediaQuery(theme.breakpoints.only('sm'));
  const extraSmall = useMediaQuery(theme.breakpoints.only('xs'));
  const columns = extraSmall ? 2 : (small ? 3 : 4);
  const maxHeightValue = extraSmall ? '22em' : '30em';
  const [imageCount, setImageCount] = useState(0);
  const {
    fetchNextPage,
    hasNextPage,
    isFetchingNextPage,
    data,
    status,
    error
  } = useInfiniteQuery(`/${Id}`, ({ pageParam = 1 }) => getImagesPage(Id, pageParam, type), {
    getNextPageParam: (lastPage, allPages) => {
      const nextPageNumber = allPages.length + 1;
      return lastPage.length ? nextPageNumber : undefined;
    }

  });

  const allImages = data ? data.pages.flat() : [];

  useEffect(() => {
    if (data) {
      setImageCount(prevCount => prevCount + data.pages.flat().length);
    }
  }, [data]);


  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      if (intObserver.current) intObserver.current.disconnect()
    }
  }, [])

  const Item = styled(Paper)(({ theme }) => ({
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.mode === 'dark' ? '#1A2027' : '#fff',
    ...theme.typography.body2,
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: theme.palette.text.secondary,
    boxSizing: 'border-box',
    lineHeight: 0,
    borderRadius: borderRadiusValue,
  }));

  const masonryContainerStyles = {
    maxHeight: maxHeightValue, // Define the maximum height you want for the scrollable box
    overflowY: 'auto',   // Make it vertically scrollable
    width: '100%',       // Full width
    padding: '1em',
    borderRadius: '15px',
    '::-webkit-scrollbar':
      { display: 'none' },
    msOverflowStyle: 'none',
    scrollbarWidth: 'none'
  };

  const intObserver = useRef();
  const lastImageRef = useCallback(image => {
    if (isFetchingNextPage) return;

    if (intObserver.current) intObserver.current.disconnect();

    intObserver.current = new IntersectionObserver(entries => {
      if (entries[0].isIntersecting && hasNextPage) {
        fetchNextPage();
      }
    }, { rootMargin: '0px' }); // Adjust this value as needed


    if (image) intObserver.current.observe(image);
  }, [isFetchingNextPage, fetchNextPage, hasNextPage]);

  if (status === 'loading') {
    return (
      <Masonry columns={4} spacing={0}>
        {[0, 1, 2, 3, 4].map((item) => (
          <Skeleton
            variant="rectangular"
            key={item}
            sx={{
              width: '100%',
              paddingBottom: '100%',
              borderRadius: '10px'
            }}
          />
        ))}
      </Masonry>
    );
  }

  const borderRadiusValue = '20px';

  const content = (
    <div style={masonryContainerStyles}>
      <Masonry columns={columns} spacing={0}>
        {allImages.map((image, i) => {
          const isLastImage = i === allImages.length - 1;
          const mediaElement = image._doc.mediaType === 'video' ? (
            <Box style={{ width: '100%', padding: 0, margin: 0, overflow: 'hidden' }}>
              <video
                src={image._doc.media}
                alt={`${listing.name} video`}
                style={{
                  maxWidth: "100%",
                  maxHeight: "auto",
                  objectFit: "cover",
                  padding: 0,
                  margin: 0
                }}
                autoPlay
                muted
                loop
              />
            </Box>
          ) : (
            <img
              src={image._doc.media}
              alt={`${listing.name} image`}
              style={{
                width: "100%",
                height: "100%",
                objectFit: "cover",
                padding: 0,
                margin: 0,
                display: 'block',
                borderRadius: borderRadiusValue
              }}
            />
          );

          return (
            <Item key={image._doc._id} ref={isLastImage ? lastImageRef : null}>
              {mediaElement}
            </Item>
          );
        })}
      </Masonry>
    </div>
  );

  return (
    <>
      {status === 'error' && <p className='center'>Error: {error.message}</p>}
      {status === 'success' && (
        data?.pages && data.pages.flat().length > 0 ? content : (
          <Box sx={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', height: '100%' }}>
            <Paper sx={{ display: 'flex', width: '80%', minHeight: '10.5em', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', flexDirection: 'column', maxHeight: '300px', '::-webkit-scrollbar': { display: 'none' }, overflow: 'auto', backgroundColor: '#F1F0E9', }}>
              {
                (small || extraSmall) ? (
                  <Box sx={{ width: '100%', display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                    <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCamera} size={'xl'} />
                    <Typography variant="h6">
                      Nothing yet, add something!
                    </Typography>
                  </Box>
                ) : (
                  <Box sx={{ width: '50%', display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                    <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCamera} size={'xl'} />
                    <Typography variant="h6">
                      Nothing yet, be the first to add something!
                    </Typography>
                  </Box>
                )
              }
            </Paper>
          </Box>
        )
      )}
      {
        (listing.medias.length < 1) &&
        <Box>
          <FileUpload type={type} listingId={listing._id} navigation={navigation} />
        </Box>
      }
      {
        (listing.medias.length > 0) &&
        <Box style={{ width: '15em', marginLeft: 'auto', marginRight: 'auto', marginTop: '-2.5em', marginBottom: '0em' }}>
          <FileUpload type={type} listingId={listing._id} navigation={navigation} />
        </Box>
      }
    </>
  );
}

export default ImageScroll;
```

I tried changing the width to zero, i tried changing it to a css file and importing it. I tried changing display size.